# BaseHTTPRequestHandler - Limit accepted range of IPs

Tags: python, server, http-headers

I am using a python script to do my webserver using the `BaseHTTPServer` module. I would like to only accept requests from a specific range of IPs. How do I do that?

**EDIT:**

I've added an code example below. How do I use the `X-Forwarded-For` instead of `self.client_address`?

```
import time
import sys
import threading
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
import urlparse
import json
from uuid import uuid4
from datetime import datetime
PORT_NUMBER = 8080

class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

  def do_GET(self):
    query_id = uuid4()

    query = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(self.path).query)
    if not "q" in query or len(query["q"][0])==0:
      self.send_error(404,'Query not found in %s' % self.path)
      return

    text = query["q"][0]
    client_ip = self.client_address[0]
    print("QUERY FROM {}: {}".format(client_ip, text))


class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    """Handle requests in a separate thread."""   

def main(_):   
  if not FLAGS.server:
    print('please specify server host:port')
    return

  try:
    server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)
    print('Started httpserver on port %d' % PORT_NUMBER)
    server.serve_forever()

  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('^C received, shutting down the web server')
    server.socket.close()
```

Comment: Use the `BaseHTTPRequestHandler.client_address` attribute. Please provide a [mcve] if you need more detail.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why I always get the value 192.168.2.50 no matter where the client is connecting from?

Comment: do you have a reverse proxy in front? Look at the the `X-FORDWARD-FOR` header instead

Comment: I'm not sure. Please see the updated question.

Comment: How do you test your server?

Comment: I connect to it from another computer on a completely different network.

Comment: Does your other computer have a proxy configured?

Comment: No. I've just tried from 3 different connections (mobile + wifi + wifi of a friend). All yield `192.168.2.50` on the server-side. Note that I'm still using the `client_address` attribute.

Comment: Presumably those networks are all external to yours. Given that the source address is in the private address range I'm guessing that you've enabled port forwarding on your router?

Comment: That might be. Sorry, I don't know as this server has been setup by another researcher a while ago.

Comment: Check the value of `self.headers` in your `do_GET()` method.

Comment: This is the content: `{'Host': <removed>, 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.13.0'}`